# Error while using JAVA FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

I am using eclipse java luna to install Java fuelSDK. I used maven to add the following dependency to my project's pom.xml:

com.github.salesforce-marketingcloud
  fuelsdk
  1.3.2

Content of my fuelsdk.properties file
clientId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
clientSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
authEndpoint=https://auth.exacttargetapis.com

In the class file I have this -

ETClient client = new ETClient("/fuelsdk.properties");
        System.out.println(client.getClientId());

When I run this I keep getting this error

Unable to locate imported document at 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/ETFrameworkFault.xsd', relative to 'jar:file:/C:/Users/sudhir.kumar/.m2/repository/com/github/salesforce-marketingcloud/fuelsdk/1.3.2/fuelsdk-1.3.2.jar!/etframework.wsdl#types1'.

I have looked into many discussions where people talked about creating the project in maven or updating the cacerts resolved their issue but i am stuck. Any HELP would be really appreciated.